# Firebase Functions - Do something every 10 minutes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cron, google-cloud-functions

I'm building an app using Firebase. There's an admin setting I want to build, that essentially populates one of my nodes with data. It would do this every 10 minutes, and there are 50-80 data points that I'd want to add.

So this would take roughly 13 hours total, I'd probably want to expand this though in the future. I would only call this function, maybe once a week.

I would simply do this using a `setTimeout` but I've heard this can be expensive? Does someone know roughly how expensive this would be?

I'm not that experienced with CRON jobs, is there a better way of doing this with Firebase? It's not something I want to have running constantly, and it's not at a specific time, but just whenever I need it. I'd also potentially want to have the job running multiple times, at the same time. Which seems to be super easy using `Firebase Functions`.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to trigger the functions from an outside source.

One way you could do that is by creating and subscribing to a pub-sub system:

```
exports.someSubscription = functions.pubsub.topic('some-subscription').onPublish((event) => {
    // Your code here
});
```

Another way you could trigger the functions is by exposing them as http requests and hitting those endpoints - See [this amazing article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) on the firebase documentation for some resources on creating http endpoints.

Both of these ways require you to have some sort of scheduling service to either publish a new event to your subscription or to hit the http endpoint. You will need to either implement these services yourself, however I am sure there are services out there that can do that for you.